# alternative approach because package ‘str_detect’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1)

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `str_detect` function in R but am getting the following error message

> package ‘str_detect’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that there's no such package as `str_detect`. `str_detect` is a *function* in the package `stringr`.